# Trying to use facebook login sdk on android and organize the code

Tags: android, static, callback, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm implementing Facebook Login on a spike for a larger project. As an attempt to organize the code (and by that I mean keeping the Activity with the button as clean as possible) I think I might have broken the actual login proccess with some major hacks. But for all I know it should work. The idea is to start another activity post-login. 
Here's my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button facebookLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
        facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_facebook_login:

                FacebookHelper.sMainActivityContext = getApplicationContext();
                LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(FacebookHelper.sCallbackManager,
                        FacebookHelper.sFacebookCallback);

                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
                        Arrays.asList(AppResources.sFacebookPermissions));

            break;
        }

    }
}
```

And the hack itself, the 'FacebookHelper' :

```
public class FacebookHelper {

    public static final CallbackManager sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    public static Context sMainActivityContext;

    public static final FacebookCallback<LoginResult> sFacebookCallback =
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(sMainActivityContext, SecondActivity.class);
                    sMainActivityContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            };

}
```

But as I press the button, the Facebook activity for the login just flashes and I'm back at MainActivity. Why does this happen? And what do I need to do to implement a working facebook login with seperated code and **not** using the LoginButton from facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should register the callback in onCreate, otherwise when your activity gets recycled due to an orientation or size change, your callback won't be added back in the new activity.
2) You have to pass the result back into callbackManager in onActivityResult.
3) If you keep a static reference to your main activity, you may have an old instance of it, if the main activity gets recycled. You should new up a callback manager in onCreate as well, and make it a class variable of the activity.

Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;


    private final FacebookCallback<LoginResult> facebookCallback =
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button facebookLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
        facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        loginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                        facebookCallback);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_facebook_login:
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
                        Arrays.asList(AppResources.sFacebookPermissions));

            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)   {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer, works like a charm, thank you! It's too bad I can't actually separate the code, but I still prefer this way way more than the LoginButton.